# Mongoose/MongoDB: Targeting specific sub-schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema in mongoose:

```
const textSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type:String, unique: true },
  sentences: [SentenceSchema],
})
```

Let's suppose that a typical text has around 100 sentences. Now I've changed one sentence up a little bit in the front-end and need to send that change to my server/mongodb. How would I best do this with mongoose+rest api? Would I update the whole article because of a change in a single sentence? Or is there a way for me to target only that very sentence that I want to change?

*PS: I am sorry, this question is probably quite basic, but it would help me out a lot! Thanks in advance for your answers!*

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to change whole article. What you can do is, you can find sentence that actually change by using sentence id and update particular sentence. You need to use findOneAndUpdate() method.

Please refer below query

```
Text.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": textId, "sentences._id": updatedSentenceId },
    { 
      "$set": {
        "sentences.$": updatedSentence
       }
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```